# CSS Grid column as wide as text but with an upper limit

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 200px) 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>Thing 1</span>
  <span>Thing 2</span>
  <span>Thing 3</span>
  <span>Thing 4</span>
</div>
```

So essentially I have a two column layout. I want the first column to be only as wide as it's content (auto) but also have an upper limit (200px). As you can see in the example above, it seems to just go all the way to 200px instead of auto. I also tried `min-content` but it yields the same result. Can I just get the first column to only be as wide as the text?

Answer (score 0):

Keep only `auto` and use `max-width` on the items:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
span:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>Thing 1</span>
  <span>Thing 2</span>
  <span>Thing 3</span>
  <span>Thing 4</span>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <span>Thing 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1</span>
  <span>Thing 2</span>
  <span>Thing 3</span>
  <span>Thing 4</span>
</div>
```

Or use `fit-content()`

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(200px) 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>Thing 1</span>
  <span>Thing 2</span>
  <span>Thing 3</span>
  <span>Thing 4</span>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <span>Thing 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1</span>
  <span>Thing 2</span>
  <span>Thing 3</span>
  <span>Thing 4</span>
</div>
```